# Does the confidence measure of a SVM have a meaning that can be compared across different models?

Tags: svm, interpretation, libsvm

Suppose I train two SVMs ($m_1$ and $m_2$) on two different (potentially unrelated) problems.

I then present datum $d_1$ to model $m_1$ and it outputs a vector $v_1$ of probabilities over the space of possible labels (using LibSVM's -b 1 option, for instance).

Then I present a different new datum $d_2$ to model $m_2$, and get $v_2$.

**Are the probabilities in $v_1$ and $v_2$ directly comparable?**

For instance, can I say that $m_1$ is more confidence in its top choice than $m_2$?

Since these are probabilities, if the models are independent, it seems like this is a straightforward yes.

However, the probabilities are (I think) derived from the geometric representation of the two distinct problems (e.g. the distance from $d_1$ to a hyperplane in $m_1$). It seems to me as though the distances in different problems are not readily comparable, so it's less clear that the probabilities are.

For example, if I trained $m_2$ on a scaled version of the data used for $m_1$, it seems like I could get very different confidence values just by exaggerating the space between points.